# Replaced Validation code in rails authentication and now can duplicate users with same details

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used a work around in my rails authentication as I kept getting an error but now the workaround has removed my user validation to check if usre already exists, I am sure there is a simple solution to this but I have tried the obvious thing and I cannot get it to work.

user.rb in models looks like this now

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
 has_secure_password
end
```

The original code which kept throwing errors was

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Can I still insert the validation into this?

Comment: What errors was it throwing, can you please post the backtrace?

Comment: Uniqueness should be enforced at the database level as well. There is nothing wrong with your original code. I'd suspect that the errors you are talking about are actually violating the uniqueness constraint, so it is doing its job. Make sure you don't have records in your database that would cause a uniqueness constraint violation.

Comment: Hi Mark, I do have duplicates now but did not before as the original error stopped me committing anything to the DB. If you could offer some pointers on how to instil a uniqueness constraint at DB level that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Use the original code which kept throwing errors, but format it this way:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps.**

Comment: `validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true` on one line is valid.

Comment: This still didn't work unfortunately, I think as mark points out it is not the formatting causing the problem but something else. Thanks for taking the time to reply though!